# Spectral radius of a hollow symmetric block matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices, spectral-radius

> Let $B$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Suppose we have a $4 \times 4$ real symmetric matrix of the following form
>
> $$A = 
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>      O_2 & B \\
>      B^T & O_2\\
>     \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> 1. What can we say about the eigenvalues of $A$?
> 2. Can we condition $B$ in a way such that the spectral radius of $A$ is less than $1$?

Comment: Have you tried computing the characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2805214/339790).